# php sort urls by ip addresses

Tags: php

Ok I posted before a question that was not so clear, so let me try again. 
I am trying to organize my websites into batches of 5 sites per batch that all have different ip addresses.

To do so I must, get IP on-the-fly for each url and then organize them, the sites, into batches of 5 sites per batch, that each have there own unique IP address.

If I have multiple IP address they must be shown on the next batch.

Can anyone help my out with this issue ?

I have the an array with sites and there IP.

Here is my code :

```
if(isset($Organize_List)){
 $List =   explode("\n", $Organize_List);
$IP_Array = array();
      foreach($List as $SIte){
    $Ip = gethostbyname(trim($SIte));
      if(preg_match('/^\d+$/', $Ip[1])){
         $IP_Array[$Ip][] = $SIte.'<br />';
                }
 }
```

Now here is where it get's tricky.

My problem is how to **organize them into batches of 5 sites per batch, that each have there own unique IP address.**

Comment: `parse_url`, `gethostbyname`, `foreach`. Enough to get you started, come back if you run into any problems with your actual code.

Comment: I have done all that, My problem is not getting the info per each site, but, aligning them all in the manor i mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* your base data */
$domains = array(/* your data */);

/* a list of domains per ip number, like $domain_by_ip['64.34.119.12'] = 'stackoverflow.com' */
$domain_by_ip = array();

/* a list counting number of domains by ip number */
$ip_count = array();

/* a list of domains we faild to fetch ip number for */
$failed = array();

/* loop through all doains */
foreach($domains as $current_domain)
{
   /* fetch the A record for all domains */
   $current_dns_record = dns_get_record($current_domain, DNS_A);

   /* if there is a dns record */
   if($current_dns_record)
   {
      /* fetch ip from result */
      $current_ip = $current_dns_record[0]['ip'];

      /* thos row is not needed, but php may triggering a warning oterhwise */
      if(!isset($domain_by_ip[$current_ip])) $domain_by_ip[$current_ip] = array();
      if(!isset$ip_count[$current_ip])) $ip_count[$current_ip] = array();

      /* add domain to the list by ip */
      $domain_by_ip[$current_ip][] = $current_dns_record;

      /* count up the count of domains on this ip */
      $ip_count[$current_ip]++;
   }
   else
   {
      /* if there was no dns record, put this domain on the fail list */
      $failed[] = $current_domain;
   }
}

/* create a list for storing batches */
$batches = array();

/* as long as we have ip-numbers left to use */
while($ip_count)
{
   /* create a list for storing current batch */
   $current_batch = array();

   /* sort ip-numbers so we take the ip-numbers whit most domains first */
   arsort($ip_count);

   /* take the top 5 ip-numbers from the list */
   $current_batch_ip_list = array_slice(array_keys($ip_count), 0, 5);

   /* foreach of thous 5 ip-numbers .. */
   foreach($current_batch_ip_list as $current_ip)
   {
      /* move one domain from the domain by ip list to the current batch */
      $current_batch[] = array_pop($domain_by_ip[$current_ip]);

      /* count down the numbers of domains left for that ip */
      $ip_count[$current_ip]--;

      /* if there is no more domains on this ip, remove it from the list */
      if($ip_count[$current_ip] == 0)
      {
         unset($ip_count[$current_ip]);
      }
   }

   /* add current batch to the list of batches */
   $batches[] = $current_batch;
}
```

Comment: First of thanks for quick replay. The code pop's off this error though: "Dns Query failed " would this work all the same if I try useing it with gethostbyname?

Comment: the dns is the way im used to get ip-adresses from, gethostbyname should work to, just replace '$current_dns_record ='-row and '$current_ip ='-row

Comment: Nice editing. All the same it pop's off this msg:
 Undefined index: 199.96.156.205

Comment: what error level do you use? and on what row is that error or warning?, its expected on the for-loop as i dont check if its exists before i add values, its not expected in the while loop

Comment: Well it didn't work out, to many errors popping up, thanks anyway. I accept your replay in any case as you are the only one kind enough to give it a shot ! thanks !

Comment: added 2 extra rows, to prevent php from triggering notices, i usely ignore notices unless i looking for an error, but i can write notice free code if i want to :-)